# How to create a wrapper function with the same annotations and parameter names as the wrapped one in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, functools

say i have a function:

```
def foo(x: Type1, y: Type2):
    do something..
```

And i want another function, say:

```
def bar(f: Callable, args..):
#do something
#return another function Fizz
```

And i want the returned function (Fizz) to have a signature like:

```
def Fizz(x: Type1, y: Type2, ...)
    pass
```

Comment: Does ``bar`` actually know the signature of ``foo`` beforehand, or does it have to dynamically create ``Fizz`` to match? Are you interested in runtime inspection (``inspect.signatures``) and/or static type analysis?

Comment: `bar` does not know `foo`'s annotations, and it would be best if it did not know it's parameter names either and still be able to include them too in `Fizz`'s signature and i am interested in runtime inspection only

Answer (score 0):

One solution i found to work is:

```
def foo(x: Type1, y: Type2):
    #do something..

def bar(func: Callable):
  func_signature = signature(func)
  params_it = iter(func_signature.parameters.values())
  x = next(params_it)
  y = next(params_it)
  def fizz(x: x.annotation, y: y.annotation):
      pass
  return fizz
```

But the limitation of that function is that assumes `foo`'s parameter names (i.e: it can't deduce it like it deduces the annotation)